# How to manage colors in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to change page color to black in `main.dart`.
I also want my other pages' background color to be black.

However the other components in Page 1-3 like `TextFormField` border are black colors. This would make it render invincible because the background color is black. How would I be able to change the `TextFormField` border's color when my background color is black?

```
main.dart
 MaterialApp
   ThemeData(
     scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
   )
   home: Scaffold
     body: Page01


Page01.dart       Page02.dart       Page03.dart
```

What is the smartest way all components colors are set.

Comment: One way you can do is to use 3rd party tools to generate a theme for your app. I have been using panache by [rxlabz](https://rxlabz.github.io/panache/#/)

Comment: Another way is to use SharedPreferences

Answer (score 2):

Define a class AppTheme with static variable.

```
class AppTheme {
static Color backgroundColor = Colors.black ;
static Color textFieldBorderColor = Colors.white ;
}
```

use AppTheme.backgroundColor to provide ThemeData

```
main.dart
 MaterialApp
   ThemeData(
     scaffoldBackgroundColor: AppTheme.backgroundColor,
   )
   home: Scaffold
     body: Page01
```

and AppTheme.textFieldBorderColor to provide textField Border Color

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
  color: AppTheme.textFieldBorderColor,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is set a variable in your `SharedPreferences` to let your app know when you want to change your `main.dart's` background color to black or not. `SharedPreferences` saves that value to the local storage so it remembers your preference even after you close the app. Don't forget to import the `SharedPreferences` package: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#-readme-tab-

You can set a variable in `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); //instantiate shared preferences
prefs.setBool("key",false) //set a boolean using key value pairs
```

After that you have to get the value by calling a function, preferably in initState()

```
bool bg_gray=false; //place this on top of widget build
getValue() async{
 if (prefs.getBool("key") == null){ //retrieve the value
     bg_grey=false;
 }
 bg_gray=prefs.getBool("key");//retrieve the value
}
```

Now that you retrieved your value, simply use ternary operators to set the color of your `TextFormField` background color

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
  color: bg_gray? Colors.white:Colors.grey,
),
```